# Safari Local Storage is empty when terminated and started

Tags: javascript, json, safari, local-storage

I am writing a simple value to Safari's local storage, if Safari is then shut down it will be able to read the value in question.

Interestingly I am able to write the data to local storage with the following code:

```
localStorage.setItem("savedData", JSON.stringify(cookieValue));
```

But when I close all instances of Safari and open a new one the local storage is shown as empty.

Does anybody know why this would happen?

Comment: Nothing looks out of place at first glance. Would need to see more code to check for anything else that might be an issue.

Comment: From a web page or a page loaded from disk?

Comment: @mplungjan It's from an .aspx web page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is rather obvious, it was my mistake from omitting some of the finer details; essentially the browser is trying to keep the secure data away from the insecure data.

The page that tries to store the data is http, whereas the page that tries to retrieve the data is https.

> localStorage is the same as
>   globalStorage[location.hostname], with
>   the exception of being scoped to an
>   HTML5 origin (scheme + hostname +
>   non-standard port) and localStorage
>   being an instance of Storage as
>   opposed to
>   globalStorage[location.hostname] being
>   an instance of StorageObsolete. For
>   example, http://example.com is not
>   able to access the same localStorage
>   object as https://example.com but they
>   can access the same globalStorage
>   item. localStorage is a standard
>   interface while globalStorage is
>   non-standard. localStorage was
>   introduced in Firefox 3.5.

From Mozilla - [DOM Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage)

I'm assuming this concept applies to all browsers, then again it's only an assumption.

Hope this helps people who may be in the same situation.